# Unable to find class for annotation for groovy script file on agent

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am not much aware of jenkins groovy coding. I am trying to get a task done on the jenkins side. So please let me know if I am doing it wrong.

I generated a groovy script on the agent dynamically using the main pipeline groovy script and in that I am trying to use a jenkins shared library.

My dynamically generated groovy file on the agent is as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/groovy
@Library('SharedLibrary')
```

If I use that same library on my pipeline script, I am able to load the library and I am able to use the variables declared in my vars folder as well in the shared library.

I am getting the following error for that file
unable to resolve class Library, unable to find class for annotation.

I tried to even use the full qualifier, or.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.Library and that did not work as well.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Thank you,
Kartik

Answer (score 0):

The correct annotation looks something like this, give this a try:

```
@Library('shared-lib') _
```

You're missing the underscore, if this does not resolve, can you share the error logs.

Comment: Hi Pratush, 

It was more of related to the groovy file being executed on the agent and not able to access jenkins tools. So, I had to change it to the grapes / grab annotation and it worked.

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved this one.
Since, I was creating a groovy file dynamically on the agent, I had to use the grab to get the imports instead of Library class which was not available due to the script not being executed on the controller.